# How to make an exception for expired token to obtain an json respons with "Token expired"

Tags: laravel, exception, jwt

I have this function :

```
public function validatePayload()
{
    if ($this->isPast($this->getValue())) {
        echo 0;
        throw new TokenExpiredException('Token has expired', 401);
    }
}
```

> But I am receiving an error message not a json response.
>   Here is my TokenExpiredException:

```
public function __construct($message, $code)
{
    parent::__construct($message, $code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your project's `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, override `render()` method:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof TokenExpiredException && $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Token has expired'
            ], 401);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

In the above code, we use `$request->wantsJson()` which uses the Accept header sent by the client and determine if it wants a JSON response.